# SQLAlchemy Core. Values method does not limit columns in insert statement

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

SQLALchemy Core [insert expressions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#insert-expressions) documentation says:

> Notice above that the INSERT statement names every column in the users table. This can be limited by using the values() method, which establishes the VALUES clause of the INSERT explicitly:

With that in mind, I wrote the following snippet, which returns unexpected results.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import types
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql


metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()

users = sqlalchemy.Table(
    "users",
    metadata,
    sqlalchemy.Column(
        "id",
        postgresql.UUID(as_uuid=True),
        default=uuid.uuid4(),
        primary_key=True,
    ),
    sqlalchemy.Column("email", types.String, unique=True, index=True),
    sqlalchemy.Column(
        "created_at",
        types.TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),
        default=datetime.utcnow(),
    ),
    sqlalchemy.Column(
        "updated_at",
        types.TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),
        default=datetime.utcnow(),
        onupdate=datetime.utcnow(),
    ),
)


email = "god@olympus.org"
query = users.insert().values(email=email)

# (Pdb) print(query)
# INSERT INTO users (id, email, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (:id, :email, :created_at, :updated_at)
#
# (Pdb) print(query.compile().params)
# {'id': None, 'email': 'god@olympus.org', 'created_at': None, 'updated_at': None}
```

I expected the query to be `INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (:email)`

Is there anything I'm missing?

I'm using `SQLAlchemy==1.3.20` by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The issue does not relate to SQLAlchemy, but rather to `encode/databases`.

[Support for "default" parameter in sqlalchemy.Column](https://github.com/encode/databases/issues/72)